# How to have an output of elements of two arrays in same line?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have two arrays and want the elements from the two arrays in the same sentence for example:

```
var a= [2,3,4,5];
var b= [12,13,14,15];
```

output should be:

```
- After 2 years, Alec will be 12 years old.
- After 3 years, Alec will be 13 years old.
```

...etc

exsiting code:

```
function newS1(){

for (var j=0; j<(a.length); j++){
    console.log('After '+ a[j] +' years,');
}
}
var a= [2,3,4,5];
var b= [12,13,14,15];

function newS2(){
    for (var i=0; i<(b.length); i++){
        console.log('Alec will be ' +b[i]+' years old');
        }

    }
newS1();
newS2();
```

Comment: Show us you existing code

Comment: So loop over the one and that reference the other....build the string....

Comment: @klugjo. the above is my existing code!

Comment: Having data in multiple arrays like this is really poor design. Use an array of objects: `[{years: 2, age: 12}, {years: 3, age: 13}, ...]`

Comment: It's also unclear why you even need arrays for this? Isn't the age always `years + 10`?

Comment: @Barmar the real code isn't like this, the above code is something i wrote just to understand the concept- the arrays above are just a sample- the real ones have more elements and are combination of strings, numbers and dates!

Comment: @Barmar- the arrays are already given too- i didn't choose to write them as multiple arrays like that.

Comment: That's too bad. You should talk to the designer of the data and help them improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through array `a` using `array#forEach` and using the index of `b`, iterate through array `b`. Generate your string using `template literals`

```js
var a= [2,3,4,5],
    b= [12,13,14,15];

a.forEach((alexAge, index) => {
  console.log(`After ${b[index]} years, Alec will be ${alexAge} years old.`);
});
```

You can use a single for loop to iterate both of your array.

```js
var a= [2,3,4,5];
var b= [12,13,14,15];

function newS1(){
  for (var j = 0; j < (a.length); j++){
      console.log('After '+ a[j] +' years, Alec will be ' +b[j]+' years old');
  }
}

newS1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the data once, using the index to get a reference to each corresponding element in each array:

```js
let yearsUntil = [2,3,4,5];
let ages = [12,13,14,15];

for (let i = 0; i < ages.length; i += 1) {
  let years = yearsUntil[i];
  let age = ages[i];

  console.log('After ' + years + ' years, Alec will be ' + age + ' years old.');
}
```

Since each item in array `a` corresponds to an item in array `b`, it would be good to refactor your data from being two parallel arrays to being one array of objects instead:

```js
let ageInfo = [
  {
    yearsUntil: 2,
    age: 12
  },
  {
    yearsUntil: 3,
    age: 13
  },
  {
    yearsUntil: 4,
    age: 14
  },
  {
    yearsUntil: 5,
    age: 15
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i < ageInfo.length; i += 1) {
  console.log('After ' + ageInfo[i].yearsUntil + ' years, Alec will be ' + ageInfo[i].age + ' years old.');
}
```

Or, since there is a consistent relationship between the two, you could just store one and calculate the other on the fly:

```js
let ages = [12,13,14,15];
let currentAge = 10;

for (let i = 0; i < ages.length; i += 1) {
  console.log('After ' + (ages[i] - currentAge) + ' years, Alec will be ' + ages[i] + ' years old.');
}
```

If you were doing a more involved calculation, you might want to move it into a [memoized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) function instead of doing it inline in the loop:

```js
let ages = [12,13,14,15];
let currentAge = 10;
let getYearsUntil = (function () {
  let cache = {};
  return function (age) {
    if (cache[age] !== undefined) {
      console.log('returning cached age.');
      return cache[age];
    }
    let yearsUntil = age - currentAge;
    cache[age] = yearsUntil;
    return yearsUntil;
  }
}());

for (let i = 0; i < ages.length; i += 1) {
  console.log('After ' + getYearsUntil(ages[i]) + ' years, Alec will be ' + ages[i] + ' years old.');
}

// calling getYearsUntil with a previously calculated age
// returns a value from the cache instead of calculating it again.
console.log(getYearsUntil(12));
```

This example uses a [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), that IIFE returns a function that is assigned to `getYearsUntil`. This allows the function that is returned to remember previous calculations that it stored in the `cache` object. For a more detailed explanation of memoization, [check out this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-memoization-in-javascript/).